# Html email Template <td> Spaces around images

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, html-table

I am coding  `html email template`   , I did slice psd to html because  of graphical work in template , now problem is that  it looks perfect in  my browsers but when I send  it to my email id there  are some problems that  you can see in attached image 
 [image]

now  this is `<tr>` with 3 `<td>` but problem is that there is gap between left blue image and logo  right one is perfectly fine , code for this `<tr>` is:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <img src="left.jpg" alt="top_left" width="220" height="102" border="0">
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <a href="http://www.google.com">
        <img src="logo.jpg" width="191" height="102" border="0" alt="Logo"></a>
    </td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <img src="right.jpg" alt="top_right" width="200" height="102" border="0">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Please let me know how I can fix it.

Comment: sir emails always use <Tables>

Comment: yes u are right  please  can u help me with it whats wrong here ?

Comment: My bet would be the table isn't constrained to the pixel width of your image(s).

Comment: i did adjust that but still it  did not work

Comment: Does the row above have 7 td's? Please post the entire table with the other rows as the colspans are dependent on what is there

Answer (score 3):

Also, make sure to always use this style on your images : display:block;

Some mail clients will do whatever they want with your code (Looking at you, gmail), and unless you specify that your images are rendered as block elements, it will add white spaces around those.

There are a couple of important fixes for gmail. Black links should always be colored as #000001 (gmail removes the black color on links, as well as on regular text for redundant content in conversations (It will turn this text purple when reposted unless you specify that the text color is #000001) ).

Also, make sure you use inline styling for your TDs height and width, sometimes the regular html value won't do.

Answer (score 0):

Remove whitespace after `a` tag. Also make sure table have cellspacing, cellpadding and border set to 0. You might need to remove all whitespace in cells.

E-mail browsers are a mess. Much more then IE6 was ;-).

Answer (score 0):

It may be an easier solution to just to use a single image if keeping the line together is important.

Unless you know what e-mail user agent each recipient is going to be using to view the e-mail, it is difficult to target them in the manner that you proposed.  Each e-mail client may use a different renderer, causing them to display the whitespace incorrectly.  There are times, when using older e-mail clients, that you will need to remove *ALL* spaces and linebreaks to get table-based formatting to display correctly; this means having all of the HTML on a single line.

Also, keep in mind that if your recipients are viewing the content in HTML5, the `border` attribute of the `img` element is obsolete; it is instead correct to add `style="border: 0;"` to the `img` element.  You may want to try using `style="margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;"` on the table cells and rows.

Make sure that you have your table set to collapse as well, using 
`<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">`